# Inserting html / javascript variable into URL window.location

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the longitude and latitude into the URL. So far I came across many different topics on the internet - but nothing is working. I posting here the html which displays the problem.

output after clicking the button "Show Position" is showing your position and changing the URL in browser with that longitude and latitude

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<script>
    function showPosition() {
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var positionInfo = "Your current position is (" + "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + ", " + "Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude + ")";
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = positionInfo;
                var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                const gotoURL = new URL(window.location.href);
                gotoURL.searchParams.set('longitude', longitude);
                gotoURL.searchParams.set('latitude', latitude);
                window.location.href = gotoURL;
            });
        } else {
            alert("Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 geolocation.");
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="result">
        <!--Position information will be inserted here-->

        <!--Position information will be inserted here-->
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="showPosition();">Show Position</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You use double quote `"` to start URL string (`"http://"`) but you concatenate variable with single quote `'`. It is not possible. Start with double quote `"` must be end with double quote. `"http://" + var`.

Comment: window.location.href = "http://177.0.0.6:5001/" + longitude - like that? it's not having any output...

Comment: See @Andy answer.

Comment: It's not really clear if you want to go to a new page immediately (in which case updating the DOM elements on the current page is fruitless), or if you want to return the URI string.  `getCurrentPosition` is an async process so if it's the latter you'll need to use a promise or async/await to get that information back.

Comment: Hey Andy, it can be the first. Directing to a new page immediately with the `http://177.0.0.6:5001/?lng=${longitude}&lat=${lattitude}`    I tried your answer snippet below...but it is not working.. I guess there is missing the window.location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There's quiet a few things wrong here... but let's try and get them sorted for you...**

- Elements don't exist. I'm guessing they previously existed before you posted this on SO. As posted above, they cause Javascript to break.

  ```
  var long = (document.getElementById('longi').innerHTML = position.coords.longitude);
  var lat = (document.getElementById('latti').innerHTML = position.coords.latitude);
  ```
- You're setting a bunch of (debug?) text and THEN (attempting to) change the URL. If everything works correctly, you'll not see the text, or you'll see it momentarily.

  ```
  var positionInfo = ...
  ```
- When you try and change the location, the variables you're trying to use (longitude and lattitude) don't exist. This is because variables declared inside a function only exist in that function (scope). You can either declare the variables before the callback function, or you can set the window location inside the callback function (this is what I'd recommend).

  ```
  window.location.href = "http://177.0.0.6:5001/?' + longitude + '' + lattitude + '";
  ```

  It's also notable that you're creating the new URL in a weird way, without the search parameters having names - You'd end up with something like 'http://177.0.0.5:5001?23.398208973.89383 - Maybe this is what you're after, but I doubt it.

The easiest way to get it working is remove the line starting with 'window.location.href' and replace the first two lines I mentioned with the following

```
const gotoURL = new URL(window.location.href);
gotoURL.searchParams.set('longitude', longitude);
gotoURL.searchParams.set('latitude', latitude);
window.location.href = gotoURL;
```

This takes advantage of the browser's URL builder to make it a little easier to create URLs.

Good luck, and I wish you all the best! ~JD

Comment: Hey JD, thank you very much. The reason why I am trying this is to get the values of longitude and latitude into flask. Do you know if this is possible? Or isnt it cause we are building a url on the users site browser... but no at the client side?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with flask. The URL you're building on client side (and redirecting to) will certainly pass the paremeters to the server, but using AJAX would likely be a better user experience

Answer (score 0):

1. You're mixing up your quotes. Maybe a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) would be easier, making sure that you're assigning those variable values to a URL parameter.

```js
const uri = `http://177.0.0.6:5001/?lng=${longitude}&lat=${lattitude}`;
```

2. Oh! You don't have a variable called `lattitude`.
3. You can make this easier for yourself by [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the properties from the `coords` object...

   ```
   const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
   ```

...and use those in the template string. And save a bit of code having to repeat things.

So your code might look like this instead.

```js
const result = document.getElementById('result');
const lat = document.getElementById('lat');
const lng = document.getElementById('lng');

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

  const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;

  const positionInfo = `Your current position is Latitude: ${latitude}, Longitude: ${longitude}`;

  result.textContext = positionInfo;

  lat.textContent = latitude;
  lng.textContent = longitude;

  const uri = `http://177.0.0.6:5001/?lng=${longitude}&lng=${latitude}`;

});
```

Comment: Dear Andy, thanks for your help. I am not sure whether I got you right. I tried to include your code in different ways but none of them was giving me any output.... I guess I am too beginner... Could you have a look at whether I got the full html right? I will update the my code above.

Comment: What output are you expecting? You said in your comment that you wanted to immediately redirect to a new page. Adding content to the current page is pointless if you're not going to see it. Did you want to log the data in localStorage so the new page can access it or something? @enving